# Does everyone needs the content packs to play together?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I want to play together with a friend of mine. However, we don't have the content packs.
Can we play on the new DLC maps and missions if only one of us buys the packs? (i.e. the host)
Or we both have to buy all the 4 packs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play on any of the DLC maps or missions online, everyone will need to own the map pack that particular map or mission comes in.

Comment: No problem. It's a major bummer. Activision loves their money, though. :p